# The same block on several pages (in different apps) django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

On the site I have a block of upcoming events. It is displayed on different pages (for each of these pages a separate view). In the template, I use {% include%} to connect "upcoming_events.html", but I don't want to use the same code in each view to get the data for "upcoming events". How best to organize the filling of the "upcoming events" block with the necessary data without duplicating the code in different places?

Answer (score 0):

You can have `Django` root level template directory which has `upcoming_events.html` and then at `Django` app level template you can extend this HTML as per your requirement. something like below...

```
 / ROOT_TEMPLATE
 - upcoming_events.html
   /APP_1
   - upcoming_events.html
   /APP_2
   - upcoming_events.html
```

Comment: No, I mean that the same code for processing upcoming_events.html is in two different views. It is much better to transfer this code to avoid duplication.